# AcceleoCompiler Deprecated

Tags: acceleo

New versions of Acceleo deprecated the AcceleoCompiler without any mention of substitute class to use. Is ANT not being supported anymore to compile Acceleo? What is the alternative way to compile outside of Eclipse?